# Asking for permission sets back navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbookui

I have 3 ViewControllers in the stack of a navigation controller. 
On the third ViewController there is a button that will add a contact to the address book.

If the app has not been used and this button is pressed the first time I am checking the authorization status and if it is `not determined` I am asking for permission with `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`.

When this was answered and the app is supposed to go back to the last VC on my navigation stack it sets back all VCs and goes alle the way back to the first VC in the navigation stack.

Is this intentional behavior?

Just in case it is useful here's the code to ask for permission:

```
else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

    // ask for access to address book.
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil), ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if (!granted){
            NSLog(@"Addressbook access was denied");
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Addressbook access was authorized");
        //[self addContactToAddressbook];
    });

}
```

(I have temporarily commented the call `addContactToAddressbook` to make sure it does not interfere.)

Comment: The dialog shouldn't do anything to your app.  Are you doing anything in response to a `didEnterForeground` event (app delegate method or notification)?

Comment: No, nothing that I am aware of. There is no `didEnterForeground`. I have edited the question to show the code that ask for permission. Independent of the answer it will always take me back to the first screen of my navigation stack.

Comment: What function is this code in? The request will complete asynchronously.  What code follows this?  What does your app do if you remove the access request entirely?

Comment: The function this is in is  `- (IBAction)addContactTapped:(id)sender {...` It will do nothing if the shown `else if` branch is not reached. If I comment out the code that asks for permission there is no other code in that function...

Comment: Btw: The code for the app is not completely mine. Others have contributed to this. So maybe there is some hidden code that does something that I am not aware of. I'll have a look through all the ViewControllers in the stack....

Comment: Found it! Thanks for your hint on "notification" and "app delegate". After answering the question `(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` is called. And in there notifications are fired which in turns lead to another functions thats does some other stuff but finally also does `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`. 
Sometimes one just needs a pointer. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete this (in case others stumble upon this). The important insight on this is:

When you call `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` to ask for permission to the address book your app seems to be in status "inactive" (while the dialog is up).

Consecutively, when the user answers the question the method:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

will be called.

(In my case this lead to resetting the navigation stack - which was the reason for my question.)